# Fedex API: Create shipping, "Your reference" fiels

Tags: .net, wsdl, fedex

I use Fedex API from .NET code (WSDL services). I create shipping lables, but I don't know how to setup "Your reference" column via API. [image: Here is an image]
Unfortunately fedex support did not reply to my question for a week.

Comment: Are you found solution?

Comment: RouR - still do not have solution. Tried to call FedEx support - no luck.